# How can I draw over other apps?

Tags: drawing

I'd like to be able to use my Asus Transformer for a presentation using the HDMI out and I'd like to be able to draw on the screen over videos, pictures and over a powerpoint presentation.  Obviously I can't be drawing and navigating simultaneously with touch but I guess I'm envisioning an "always on top" floating dock or tool bar to toggle between the "paint" function and the normal touch input.

To be clear I'm not interested in specific "drawing" apps, I'm looking for the ability to draw persistently over any and every open app.

Is there an app or hack that will accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

In my old school days, this were trivial because just right behind the projector screen are whiteboards which is sometimes used as a "screen" which can be drawn on with markers.

As more modern alternative, there are also smartboards that provides a virtual whiteboard to draw on with digital annotations. And one of them [can be controlled and viewed from an Android tablet](http://suefrantz.com/2012/06/24/smartboard-alternative-using-a-tablet/).

If you only need video and slides, then you can run your presentation on the computer running smartboard software and connect to the computer with the Android tablet controller. This doesn't actually allow you to draw over arbitrary apps though.

Comment: Yes but we've done away with projectors and now we just run our presentations on a 50" LCD display.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old question, but I was looking for the same thing and finally ran across an app that does this.

Ink Over Apps

This is an old app that you need to download from a site that has old apk files. [here is a link](https://www.apksum.com/app/ink-over-apps/com.ntkachov.penandpaper) to one of them.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually an app available on goole play. Its called.
[Draw On App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kts.draw&hl=en_US). This is a great app with options to change color, make the the pen size larger and erase as well.

There are many more apps there. Just search for draw on app, you'll see a nice few of them.